# Problema com palavras que usam aspas ao fazer INSERT SQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli, formulário, input, sql-insert

Estou com problemas quando vou realizar o insert no mysql quando eu tenho uma palavra que contem Aspas ex (caixa ***d'agua***) em qualquer input do form, quando mando gravar da erro no mysql. Já mudei o Charset e não tive sucesso! O script funciona perfeitamente grava todos os dados e tal. Porém se aparecer alguma palavra com aspas da erro!
Como se resolve isso?

Estou utilizando PHP e MYSQL

Comment: Bem-vindo André Luis Diego, quanto a pergunta "Alguém já passou por isso?" a resposta curta é "SIM"

Comment: Se a pergunta fosse "Como se resolve isso?" a resposta seria "tem que escapar a aspas" veja como em https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php

Comment: Leo vlw pela dica consegui resolver muito obrigado amigo a vc e ao Junio

Comment: Aconselho a dar uma olhada em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola amigo não sei qual linguagem esta usando para seu script
porem direto no sgbd pode realizar dessas duas formas.

```
INSERT INTO professor
VALUES ('caixa d\'agua');


INSERT INTO professor
VALUES ("caixa d'agua");
```

Comment: Deu certo cara, vlw pela dica salvou o dia obg

Answer (score 0):

Inserir um dado no banco de dados contendo alguns tipos de caracteres, podem causar erro.

PHP-MySQL: Inserindo aspas simples, aspa dupla no banco de dados

Caracteres que podem causar problemas de inserção: apóstrofo `(')`, aspas `(")` e barra invertida `(\)`.

Exemplo de texto a ser gravado:

```
Olá Sra. Caixa d'agua, seja bem-vinda ao ‘stackoverflow’
```

Imagine que você digitou o texto acima num campo do seu formulário e agora quer gravar no banco. Se fizer o insert direto deste texto vai dar erro.

Para resolver este problema você vai precisar da função addslashes();

```
  $texto = addslashes($_POST['texto']);
  INSERT INTO tabela (texto) VALUES ('$texto');
```

Outra solução:

```
$texto = filter_var($_POST['texto'], FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
```

Fontes:

[FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/filter_sanitize_magic_quotes.asp)

[addslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php)